# Updating a list element that was initialized with zero value with string - does it create a copy or override?

Tags: python

My question is in general about lists and data types. 
In case that I initialize a dictionary of lists beforehand with zeros (in order to update these values along the program) as following:

```
data = defaultdict(list)

class sLabel:
    TotalTrx = 0
    Week = 1
    Day = 2
    Hour = 3
    POD = 4


def init(sID):    
    for i in [attr for attr in dir(sLabel) if not callable(attr) and not attr.startswith("__")]:
        data[sID].append(0)
```

I'm updating this list with zeros but some elements will be updated with string values.
My question is, will this create a copy or override the specific element?

second question, if it does create a copy, what is the right and cleanest way to initialize a dictionary of list with different data types?

Comment: Create a copy of what? Replacing a single value in a list doesn't replace the list - lists are mutable, they can be changed in-place. And lists in Python aren't typed, they can hold a mix of different types (although `None` might be a more sensible default than `0`).

Comment: what is 'sID' in your code ? Actually your code raises a `NameError`... And what are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: For example data[0][0] is zero, and then, I change it to data[0][0] = 'Hey'. Will it take new space in memory? (pointer wise)

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers fixed, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following snippet answers your question:

```
>>> a = [0, 0, 0] # create list full of zeroes
>>> b = a # create second reference to same list
>>> a[1] = "foo" # replace one int with string
>>> a
[0, 'foo', 0] # definitely changed a
>>> b
[0, 'foo', 0] # b also changed, so still referencing same object
>>> a is b
True # yes, definitely still the same object
```

Lists are *mutable*, they can be changed in-place. They hold *references to objects*, so it doesn't matter what type of objects you put in the list (and the real size of the list only reflects the number of objects in it, not the underlying size of those objects).

If you want to create a copy, you must do so explicitly (e.g. `b = a[:]`).